# Docker: User localhost instead of db to connect to PostgresDatabase

Tags: django, docker

I'm running into problems when using Docker. To connect from Django application to the Postgres database I have to use:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

However to run tests via pytest in my Pipenv shell I have to change 'Host': from `db` to `localhost`. Is there a way that I can always use localhost?

Docker-Compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  web:
    build: .
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    container_name: test
```

Dockerfile:

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3

# Set environment varibles
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pipenv
COPY ./Pipfile /code/Pipfile
RUN pipenv install --deploy --system --skip-lock --dev

# Define ENTRYPOINT
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

# Copy project
COPY . /code/
```

Comment: May I ask why you don't want to use docker postgres db for testing?

Comment: Why aren't you executing your tests by executing `python manage.py test`? Django will create a test database on its own.

Comment: It would actually be my preferred approach @ruddra 
I tried to run pytest by accessing `docker exec -it test bash`

However, the tests seem to have no access to the database either. (Or have no access to create a test database.) It always fails.

Comment: @JonProgrammer I have similar setup as yours, I face no problem running tests from shell. My setup is available in [github](https://github.com/ruddra/docker-django)

Comment: Thank you for sharing it ruddra. Do you also use pytest in your shell?

Comment: Yes I have, and did not face any issue with it either.

Comment: can you share the exact stack trace please?

Comment: Sure! https://pastebin.com/B1TNPXDS